# Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function at $a$. Find $\lim \limits_{x\to a} \frac{a^nf(x)-x^nf(a)}{x-a}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that I will probably use the definition of a derivative to prove it, but I am not sure how to exactly go about it. The $a^n$ and $x^n$ are throwing me off.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Rewrite our expression as
$$\frac{a^n f(x)-a^nf(a)+a^n f(a)-x^n f(a)}{x-a}.$$

Comment: I rewrote the expression that way then got stuck here: a^n*f'(a)+(a^n-x^n)*f(a)/(x-a)

Comment: Maybe I should have been nice and written the top as $a^n(f(x)-f(a))-f(a)(x^n-a^n)$. So the limit of the second part is $-f(a)\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}$. You will recognize the limit as the derivative of $x^n$ at $x=a$. Or else you can factor $x^n-a^n$ as $(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+\cdots +a^{n-1})$. So we should end up with $a^nf'(a)-(f(a))na^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write this as $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\bigg(\frac{\frac{f(x)}{x^n}-\frac{f(a)}{a^n}}{x-a}\bigg)\cdot a^nx^n=g^{\prime}(a)\cdot a^{2n}$,

where $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

L'Hospital says
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{a^nf(x)-x^nf(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{a^nf'(x)-nx^{n-1}f(a)}{1}
$$
However, technically, this requires $f$ to be differentiable near $a$. If you don't know that, then André Nicolas' approach works.